# comparison test

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to use comparison test to determine whether if the following series is convergent or divergent. The ratio is inconclusive as the obtained limit is 1 .

$\sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{6n^2+1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$

So at high n values the series will be almost equal to:
$\frac{1}{n}$
and so using harmonic p series, since the power of n=1, then the series is divergent. Which means that we need to find an equation smaller than the original series.

I am totally lost at finding such equation, I've tried this:
$\frac{6n^2+1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$ > $\frac{n^2}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$

But then the right handside equation does not get reduced to a $\frac{1}{n}$ form. Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: For sufficiently high values of $n$ we have $\frac{6n^2+1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}> \frac{n^2+4n+4}{(n+2)^3}=\frac{1}{n+2}$  The change in the denominator should be clear as we made the denominator larger.  The change in the numerator follows from that $5n^2\geq 4n+4$ for sufficiently large $n$ (*in particular all $n\geq 2$*)

Comment: That's pretty good, but would it be a problem that n=1 for the series (not 2)?

Comment: Nope, doesn't matter since the first finitely many terms only contribute a finite amount to the total sum.  The fact that it diverges depends only on the nature of the tail terms.

Comment: Totally off-topic but added for your curiosity : sooner or later, you will learn that there is a closed form expression for the partial sums.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that when $n$ is large, only the highest powers of $n$ will matter.  If you want to find a lower bound, you should "round down" the numerator and "round up" the denominator to a multiple of the highest power of $n$ appearing.  In this case, you might round down $6n^2+1$ to $6n^2$ and round up $n(n+1)(n+2)=n^3+3n^2+2n$ to $2n^3$.  So you might guess that for all sufficiently large $n$, $$\frac{6n^2+1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}\geq\frac{6n^2}{2n^3}=\frac{3}{n}.$$  Now can you prove that this inequality actually is true for all sufficiently large $n$?

Comment: Can we use limit to prove that $\ n^3 > 3n^2+2n$\

Comment: showing that: $$ \lim_{n\to ∞} \frac{(3n^2+2n)}{n^3} = 0 $$

Answer (score 1):

$6n^2+1=2n^2+4n^2+1>2n^2+4n>2n^2+3n$ so
$$\dfrac{6n^2+1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}>\dfrac{2n+3}{(n+1)(n+2)}=\dfrac{1}{n+1}+\dfrac{1}{n+2}$$

Comment: So is it a property that when two divergent series added together, the result also diverges?

Comment: They are one
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\dfrac{1}{n+1}+\dfrac{1}{n+2}\right)=\dfrac12+2\sum_{n=2}^\infty\dfrac{1}{n+1}$$

Comment: So long as all terms are non-negative, that is fine.  The series where you add nothing but positive 1's added to its negative where the series are added term by term though is an example of where that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

For $n\geq 2, $$$\dfrac{6n^2+1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}>\dfrac{n^2}{\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}}=\frac{n^2}{1+2^2+3^3+\dots+n^2}>\frac{n^2}{n^2+n^2+\dots+n^2}=\frac{1}{n}$$

Then $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{6n^2+1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}>\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$$

Hence diverges.